# Sprite Looking Weird on iPhone Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, render

I am looking to modify this project but the game renders weird when running on iPhone. When I run it on macOS or iPad it looks fine but when I try to load it on iPhone it runs into issues. I don't think it's a sizing thing or browser thing because it does the same thing with iOS chrome and safari and works completely fine on macOS and iPadOS safari and chrome. For sizing, I tried the chrome dev tools iPhone size and it did not have any issues working properly. Let me know if you have a solution I am very confused on how to solve this issue! Thanks!

Expected behavior: [Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GIWa.png)
Unexpected behavior: [Unexpected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8F5Y.jpg)

Source code:
https://github.com/dominikgorczyca/Pac-Man

Game demo:
https://dominikgorczyca.github.io/Pac-Man/

I don't know where to start to solve this issue. I'm expecting the map to generate properly on mobile devices but it does not. Some code that may be relevant from the GitHub repo for how it is supposed to generate the map:

```
#game-board {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 56rem;
    height: 62rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(28, 2rem);
}
/* GAME BOARD GENERAL */

#game-board > * {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
}

#start, #game-start {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    top: 54%;
    text-align: center;
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    z-index: 1;
    user-select: none;
}

/* OBJECTS AND WALLS  */
.wall {
    background-image: url("map.png");
    z-index: 1;
}
@media (max-width: 600px), (max-height: 700px) {
    .wall {
        background-image: url("small_map.png");
    }
}

.blank {
    background-color: black;
}

.wall > * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    border: .2rem solid #161693;
    border-radius: 80%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.point,
.big-point {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    background-color: #ffb897;
    border-radius: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

.point {
    border: .8rem solid black;
}

.big-point {
    border: .4rem solid black;
    border-radius: 45%;
    background-color: #ffb897;
}
.gate {
    background-color: #ffb897;
    border-top: .7rem solid black;
    border-bottom: .7rem solid black;
}
```